# Is it feasible to call ScaLAPACK routines from Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have been tasked with the maintenance of a set of old FORTRAN scientific codes, mostly written using MPI parallelization, to be run in thousand+ node clusters. New features are always difficult to retrofit, and my boss has allowed me to go for partial rewrites of specific components. I'd like to give Erlang a go, but my experience is limited and I was wondering if it would be difficult to call ScaLAPACK routines from Erlang. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by integrating the routines as NIFs (or using a port driver), but you'd need to get down to some really low level details, which is probably not what you want for a first Erlang project.

Maybe the [Disco Project](http://discoproject.org/) could be something for you. It uses Erlang for distribution, but lets you script the individual jobs in Python, which already has good support for calling scientific code.